# Chatter Communities Different Feeds

Tags: community, chatter, chatter-feed

We have a customer who interacts with different companies for cases. So we will have 3 communities. 
I'm wondering if it's possible to make it so that each community can only see posts that are made by them.

Eg:

- There is a case from a Customer(Community 1), but I need info from
  the Store(Community 2) where the Customer bought his product.
- The question I ask via chatter should not be visible for the
  Customer. Only for the Store.
- Also the Store can't see previous posts between me and the customer.
  It's also possible I need information from the Manufacturer(Community
  3) of the product. This should also be hidden from the other 2
  communities.

So the main question, is this possible? If possible, please discuss how to initiate the set up.

Answer (score 0):

A user will be able to see any post they have access to. Access is governed by the parent of the Chatter Post. 
Example: If a post is made in a community and a user has access to that community then they will see the post.

A Post in 1 community wont just show up in a different community. Unless it is on an object that is visible in both communities. In which case the posts will be visible to whoever has access to that object.